# Separating JS from HTML using external JS file

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, html, google-visualization

I'm building charts using the Google Chart API. Till now all my function to draw the charts are inside the front page. They are working fine however I have a lot of code inside the front page. I'm trying to put the java script functions to draw the charts into and external java script file however nothing is being drawn.

I created a demo so that it is easy to understand and to test.
This is my HTML (Default.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

//      function drawChart() {

//          var dataValues = eval('<%=getJsonObj()%>')
//          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataValues);
//          data.addColumn('string', 'NAME');
//          data.addColumn('number', 'NUMBER');

//          for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
//              data.addRow([dataValues[i].name, dataValues[i].number]);
//          }

//          var options = { 'title': 'Pie Chart Example' };

//          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
//          chart.draw(data, options);
//      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="drawChart()" value="Draw Pie Chart" />
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Code Behind (Default.aspx.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string getJsonObj()
    {
        List<Item> data = new List<Item>();
        data.Add(new Item("AAA", 10));
        data.Add(new Item("BBB", 20));
        data.Add(new Item("CCC", 30));

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = jss.Serialize(data);
        return json;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string name = "";
    public int number = 0;

    public Item(string iName, int iNumber)
    {
        name = iName;
        number = iNumber;
    }
}
```

And this is the external js (Test.js)

```
function drawChart() {

    var dataValues = eval('<%=getJsonObj()%>')
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataValues);
    data.addColumn('string', 'NAME');
    data.addColumn('number', 'NUMBER');

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].name, dataValues[i].number]);
    }

    var options = { 'title': 'Pie Chart Example' };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

If I use the commented function in the Default.aspx it works fine. However I want to obtain th same result usting the drawChart in the external js file so I minimize the code in the front page.
I need to understand why this code does not work and what has to be done to get it working.

Comment: you couldn't put eval('<%=getJsonObj()%>') in your external js file , because asp.net don't expand the expression, you could pass your expression result in the js function call as parameter

Comment: Have you tried opening the debugging tools to see if you have any JavaScript errors?

Comment: When I debug I do not get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about ASP, but I do see that you include your Test.js before you include the Google JSAPI. In your Test.js you use classes defined in the JSAPI, so you'll have to include this first and you will have to call `google.load()` before you call the function `drawChart()`

Answer (score 1):

Invert the order of inclusion of your files:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"></script>
```

then:

```
<input type="button" onclick="drawChart()" value="Draw Pie Chart" />
```

should be

```
<input type="button" onclick="drawChart('<%=getJsonObj()%>')" value="Draw Pie Chart" />
```

so your function should be something like this:

```
function drawChart(jsonObj) {

    var dataValues = eval(jsonObj);
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataValues);
    data.addColumn('string', 'NAME');
    data.addColumn('number', 'NUMBER');

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].name, dataValues[i].number]);
    }

    var options = { 'title': 'Pie Chart Example' };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

You could also avoid to 'eval' your object and use instead JSON.Parse, and use unobtrusive javascript instead of onclick=drawChart

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I arranged the code but still can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

just add the path to your script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/script"/></script>
    </body>
</html>
```